# Scala.js val's produce null, but lazy vals work as expeced

Tags: javascript, null, scala.js

I've been noticing a strange behaviour in Scala.js
To give a minimum example:

```
trait T {
  val votes: Int = 1
}

class A extends T

class Reader(a: A) {
  println(a.votes)
}
```

this will print `null`, but if I make votes `lazy` everything works fine.

Has anyone seen similar behaviour?

Comment: Hum, how do you create `Reader`? Also, does it behave differently on Scala JVM? Otherwise you might just have hit Scala's initialization order.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. See: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ZSx3HDm/0

Comment: @sjrd does scala fiddle run scala.js?

Comment: @gzm0 i have not tested on jvm

Comment: @Andrey Yes, ScalaFiddle runs Scala.js.